# Passenger + Apache Ubuntu 10.04 blank logs

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to host Rails with Apache and Passenger. I've gone through installation guides on both my hosts site and Phusion's Documentation site, but both Apache's and Rails' logs are blank when I go to test it.

I've created a fresh Rails app with a test controller to display a test message and configured a vhost as advised in the guides. I can render the static "Welcome to Rails" content no problem but the controller is coming back with the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message.

Any advice for debugging this? Pulling my hair out without error messages in the logs. Isn't Passenger Deployment supposed to be easier than Mongrel? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I reinstalled everthing and am now getting error messages in the rails logs. Hate not knowing what you fixed! :/